Archimedes' approximation of length of a curve
I have been told by a colleague that the following way of approximating the length of a curve is due to Archimedes (he heard of it somewhere in Greece) but we could't find any reference. Let me describe the setting.
I consider two ways of connecting points $p=(r_0, \theta_0), q=(r_1, \theta_1) \in X:=[0,+\infty)^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ expressed in polar coordinates:

A circular movement: I only move along circles centred at the origin. If $r_0=r_1$, I move on the circle of radius $r_0$ centred at the origin from the angle $\theta_0$ to $\theta_1$. The length of this path is $C(p,q):=r_0 |\theta_0-\theta_1|$. If $r_0 \ne r_1$ this is impossible and thus $C(p,q)=+\infty$.
A radial movement: I only move along radial segments. Here there are two possibilities, either $\theta_0=\theta_1$ and thus I can move directly on the same segment from the first point to the second, or $\theta_0 \ne \theta_1$ so that I can go first from the first point to the origin along a segment and then from the origin to the second point along another segment. The length of this path is either $R(p,q)=|r_0-r_1|$ or $R(p,q)=r_0+r_1$.

I would like to understand if it is possible to approximate the length of a smooth curve $\gamma:[0,1] \to X$ with paths made of these kind of movements: this is to say that
$$\text{length}^2(\gamma)= \liminf_K \inf \left \{ K \sum_{i=1}^K (R^2(\gamma(t_{i-1}),q_i)+ C^2(q_i, \gamma(t_i)) \right \}$$
where the infimum is taken among the collections of times $0=t_0 \le t_1 \le t_{K-1} \le t_K=1$ and points $q_1, \dots, q_K \in X$.
Any reference to this kind of construction would be highly appreciated.
